# My Bash or zsh or terminal not working anymore

Tags: bash, terminal, shell, zsh, iterm2

I know this is probably a simple fix.

But I had my terminal set up perfectly, using a bash profile as default. Then i installed iTerm and now nothing works.

I cant even run the ls command when in a directory.

this is the output i get when i open a new terminal window.

```
-bash: dirname: command not found
-bash: dirname: command not found

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
Name's-MacBook-Pro-2:~ name$
```

Even if i try to set the default to zsh i get:

-bash: chsh: command not found

Im really not sure whats happened.

if i run

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

then everything works again. But if i restart terminal then it doesnt again and i need to re eport the path.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that exporting PATH with the standardized defaults fixes it temporarily points to a bad `export PATH="..."` in one of the initialization files loaded by the shell at startup.

They should be like: `export PATH="$PATH:/some/path"`. With the `$PATH` part missing in the assignment it would destroy the current value of the environment variable `PATH` rather than adding to it, and leave you in a situation like this.

`/bin/echo $PATH` should show you the value of PATH. If you do this in a fresh shell without the manual export fix you're using it will give you a clue to help find where the PATH is being overwritten.

[Somewhat relevant Q + A's on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15101559/7665043), specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15104697/7665043) leads to:

Check `~/.bash_profile` and if there's a line with `export PATH="..."` that doesn't include `$PATH` in the assignment, add it in. Just make sure to put a `:` between paths, as that's the separator. e.g. `export PATH="$PATH:/some/path:another/path"` would safely add both `/some/path` and `another/path`.

If `~/.bash_profile` contains either/both of `source $HOME/.profile` or `source $HOME/.bashrc`, or it wasn't found & fixed in `.bash_profile`, then check those files too. Also note that `.` is an alias for `source`, and so it may say `. $HOME/.profile`, etc.

The above answer also notes that in both Terminal and iTerm (with default settings) new shells are "login shells" by default and do not read `~/.bashrc`. So, if you're following directions for a non-Mac OS (Linux, etc) try adding what they say to `~/.bash_profile` instead.

You could `source $HOME/.bashrc` in your `~/.bash_profile` if you wish to do so, but as it's not supposed to be loaded in a login shell this may lead to trouble at some point.

Also, just in case, note that `~` is only expanded to `/home/{user}` on the commandline. `$HOME` must be used for the same effect in scripts, but can also be used from the commandline.